# How to protect shell script's code

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I Have a shell script. I've to make it available for all the users for EXECUTION only. And i've to hide/protect the content in it. So, nobody will not copy that file. Is there anyway to do like password protection for read or encrypting the script ? Please suggest me.

Comment: Regarding enciphering script see my answer <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871805/how-to-create-a-password-protected-shell-script/15873870#15873870">here</a>.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly scripts are not intended to be hidden. May be you should implement your secret algorithm in some programming language and then and  execute that algorithm from script.
You would also not need password since executables are binary files and are not human readable.

You just need to know what goes into the program and what goes in the script.

Comment: My script is in `/etc/MyScript.sh` and I changed this to `711` mode already, that is not working (711 will not work with shell scripts). The normal user is not able to execute/read/write. It should allow to execute, but not to read or write or delete.

Comment: Is there any way to make the script password protected for read/write ?

Comment: That doesn't work, because the user's shell has to be able to read the script in order to execute it. The shell (`sh`, `bash`, or whatever) is the actual executable being run with the user's privileges; the script is an input file being read by the shell.

Comment: Ya. How stupid mistake I have made.. It was so obvious. Please check the edited post.

Answer (score 1):

Make the script readable only by some specified account, and provide an executable, `setuid` to that account, that runs the script.

Of course that means the script will run with the specified account's privileges rather than the user's privileges.

Answer (score 0):

It`s not best practice (why you have such requirement ?!) but you can use SHC - shell script compiler.

SHC link : http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/

Comment: I have some user's who could probably create a similar script with the same configurations. And it will cause serious issue. So, i don't want to make the read/write/delete permission to them, just provide the "execute" permission.

Comment: so then all you need is chmod

Comment: 711 will not work with shell scripts. Is there any way to make the script password protected for read/write ?