# Bash protect a script from getting copied by users

Tags: bash, security, scripting

I recently wrote a bash script that calculates the number of worked hours in a month given the  arrival/departure times for each day. Some coworkers are interested to purchase it. But I just want them to be able to execute the file, and not be able to change the code, or send it to others to use for free. I know I can use the chmod command to set permissions, but so can they. Is there any other command or program that I could use to protect the script from getting copied or attached in an email?

also let me know if you think this is not related to "stackoverflow.com"

**EDIT:**
OK here is what I want to know specifically:
Is there anyway that you can set a bash script to rx permissions so users can only run the script, without them being able to change the permissions? My problem is that the users can change the permissions using the chmod command as well. All users use Windows, so the script will be run using Cygwin. I can write a C/C++ or a Java program that does the same thing, but I want to know how to do this for a bash script bash, cause I'm learning bash. I rather not implement password protected script as long as possible.

I'm not too worried if the users can change this script, but I'm REALLY interested to know if there is a not too complicated way to do this for my future references, since I'm planning to do a lot of bash scripts.

Please leave a comment if the question is still to broad, or if I still need to edit the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to protect shell script's code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15871075/how-to-protect-shell-scripts-code)

Comment: They are similar, but note that the other question is asking how to use passwords to protect a script, while I'm interested to know how to protect a script(or file) when compiling/saving or use another program to do that after script fully written. I have no desire to create a password protected script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're on a Unix-like system and have access to a C compiler, and don't mind that people with `root` privileges (or `sudo` privileges) can get at the script after all, then you could consider, cautiously, using a SUID program to run the script.

Set the permissions on the script, `worked_hours` to 500 (read and execute for owner only) in a directory which other people cannot modify (I'll assume `/home/you/bin/worked_hours`).  Note that to be truly safe, other people should not be able to modify `/` or `/home` or `/home/you` or `/home/you/bin` — and you can't stop `root` from modifying those directories, so you have to trust your `root`-privileged users.

Create a program `hours_worked` from source code `hours_worked.c`:

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    argv[0] = "/home/you/bin/worked_hours";
    execv(argv[0], argv);
    return 1;
}
```

Compile it, and place in a directory you trust where other people can use it but not modify it — so 755 permission on a directory you own — I'll assume you use `/home/you/bin`.  Set the permissions on `hours_worked` to 4511 (SUID, readable and executable by the owner — `you` — and executable by others).

Now tell people to run `/home/you/bin/hours_worked`.  They can't read this executable; they can't read the shell script it runs.  But the executable can run the shell script.  As long as you're confident that the script has the necessary privileges when run as yourself, you should be fine.  (Unless someone has screwed around with `bash` so that it resets the effective UID to be the real UID, or anything silly — or, at minimum, inconvenient — like that.)

Where are the security risks?  I'm assuming that you can control your home directory and the `bin` directory under it and that you trust your colleagues with super-user privileges on your machine not to abuse their privileges to read the script, etc.  You simply can't reliably stop people with super-user privileges.  Many risks are avoided by the minimal number of lines of code in the program.  Using an absolute path like that is about as safe as you can make it.  The code does relay command line arguments from the user to the script.

It does assume you can write a sufficiently secure shell script — which is problematic.  Note that all commands run by the script will be run as if you were running it.  If your script runs an editor, or runs a program that runs an editor, you have to assume that the users will be able to get to a shell and run arbitrary commands with your privileges.  Any emails sent will (most likely) be sent as if it was you doing the sending.  Etc.  Making sure that all works as intended is tricky.  If you can create an alter ego user (different user name and user ID) and make the program SUID to that user (and that user owns the script too), then you can avoid being directly implicated — but it implies you have `root` privileges on the machine to set up the alter ego user.  You will want to be confident that the script is running the programs you want it to run and not the programs your users want it to run.  Amongst other things, you'll need to consider the setting of PATH, and also worry about `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_PRELOAD` or their equivalents (though the fact that the program is SUID should prevent the `LD_*` variables being used).

Is this sufficient?  As I've clearly stated, it is not perfect because you have to trust `root`-privileged users.  If you can trust them, it is moderately effective.  It is far from perfect, but then so are all the other techniques.  With an alter ego user owning and running the script, you can get reasonable security.  If you need to, you can write a similar program to undo SUID permissions:

```
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    setegid(getgid());
    seteuid(getuid());
    execv(argv[1], &argv[1]);
    return 1;
}
```

Call it `unsetsugid`.  Prefix any scary commands (editors, etc) run in your secret script with `unsetsugid`:

```
/home/you/bin/unsetsugid vim /tmp/xyz
```

This means that anyone who runs the script will run the editor as themselves without your privileges.  Tricky, but helpful.

Do I think this is a good idea?  No, not really.  Why are so worried about the secrecy?  It is the antithesis of open source.  You never know, they might spot a problem in your code.

Comment: Thanks a LOT for the info. I was honestly more interested to see the solution to this problem than hiding my code from the users. I don't mind them see the problem, just didn't want them to change it. I really like your answer. Though I'm surprised after all these years no-one came up with a one liner solution. After reading all this I don't think I'll be restricting them anymore.

Comment: As you can tell from the legion of caveats laced into the answer, there are several reasons why it isn't done — one of which is that it is hard to make it secure, and another of which is that it usually isn't worth the effort.  The `shc` solution is interesting; the fact that it can readily be broken is also interesting.  Root privileges limit the effectiveness of any solution. All of which adds up to 'there is not much incentive to make it work effectively'.

Answer (score 1):

There's no real way to do this. What you're asking for is copy protection, which nobody has ever figured out a good way to do. Basically, in order to execute the script, their computer must be able to read it; if something you don't have control over can read the script, you have lost control of the script.

For a shell script, the probably the closest you could come would be to encrypt and "compile" the script with [shc](http://www.datsi.fi.upm.es/~frosal/) (instructions [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/encrypt-bash-shell-script/)). However, anyone with read access to the encrypted executable can [decrypt it](http://www.l0d.org/Decrypt_an_shc_crypted_file.html), recover the original script, and copy/modify/do whatever they want with it.